# How can I create a round icon image with OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I'm using openlayers inside my ionic app. Now i'm placing users on map. I'm stuck and i'have no idea how to add some custom css style to user element since it's not visible present in html. As you can see in screenshot below i draw circle in background and over it i add image. Now i want that image to be round too. Most simple thing is with css, but i'm not able to add it to element.

Example map:
https://gyazo.com/3fb6b2e3565572b0c0a64044c645e364

Part of code where i'm defining circle and icon: https://gyazo.com/cc80d368dfa8874739be14ce09eadffd

Inspected map:
https://gyazo.com/7fadd75cfd4f9e517b76300b4c1b3c9c

Comment: You can set a border-radius in the style to 10000

Comment: But how, check the last screenshot. Map is actually canvas where everything is drawn, there are no exposed elements like img's or some div's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found workaround for [this](https://gyazo.com/0803c9dff82823c47ca4c3fa37c90d34). 
Instead using ol.Feature for markers, i've did it with ol.Overlay. Now i can put any html [element](https://gyazo.com/5a0fd6a3622e7bc344dfc58b2e7e4acb) on map and control it however i want, since it is accessible in html. [(screen #2)](https://gyazo.com/25fe270c5d8228fc79987d2931011bf1)

```
updateMarkers(featuresArr) {

for(var i = 0; i < featuresArr.length; i++)
{
  var overlayelement = new ol.Overlay({
    stopEvent: false,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: document.getElementById('slika')
  });
  overlayelement.setPosition(featuresArr[i].getGeometry().getCoordinates());

  this.olMap.addOverlay(overlayelement);

}}
```